# How to resolve "cannot get window" error in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I am learning kivy. kivy's errors leave me highly disappointed. I have visited every github and stack overflow page including kivy.readthedocs.io and obeyed every suggestion....

### what i have:

kivy 1.11.1 (somehow managed to install it from unofficial binaries website),
python 3.9.1,
pycharm community version-latest,

My code:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.1')
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.slider import Slider
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout

class WidgetContainer(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(WidgetContainer,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols=4
        self.add_widget(Label(text="volume"))
        self.volumeControl=Slider(max=100,min=0)
        self.add_widget(self.volumeControl)
        self.volumeValue=Label(text="0")
        self.add_widget(self.volumeValue)
        self.volumeControl.bind(value=self.on_press)
    def on_press(self,instance,volume):
        self.volumeValue.text=str(volume)
class SliderThingy(App):
    def build(self):
        widgets=WidgetContainer()
        return widgets
root=SliderThingy()
root.run()
```

the output:

```
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.9.0 (tags/v3.9.0:9cf6752, Oct  5 2020, 15:34:40) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_pil, img_gif (img_sdl2, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: pil(['text_sdl2'] ignored)
[CRITICAL] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window provider. Please enable debug logging (e.g. add -d if running from the command line, or change the log level in the config) and re-run your app to identify potential causes
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _window_sdl2: The specified module could not be found.
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 59, in core_select_lib
    mod = __import__(name='{2}.{0}.{1}'.format(
  File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from kivy.core.window._window_sdl2 import _WindowSDL2Storage

[CRITICAL] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

### what i have tried:

installing packages from pycharm,
installing packages from venv,
running my code from venv.

All of that keeps on giving me the same errors.....

*A working answer will be highly appreciated*

Comment: Kivy 1.11.1 probably isn't compatible with Python 3.9, try Kivy 2.0.0.rc4 instead (and install with pip)

Comment: Or try Python 3.7

Comment: you are must be answering from your experience, thanks. But it ultimately worked when i uninstalled and reinstalled an appropriate version of kivy-deps.gstreamer using ```pip install -Iv kivy_deps.gstreamer==.....``` the rest i don't remember  (;-;) ...

Comment: but how do i upvote your comments on my pc -_-